# Getting System.MissingMethodException with MessageBox.Avalonia

Tags: c#, windows, messagebox, avaloniaui, missingmethodexception

I'm trying to display message boxes in [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) with C# on Windows.

My package versions are as follows:

[image]

My code for displaying a message box is:

```
using MessageBox.Avalonia;
using MessageBox.Avalonia.DTO;
using MessageBox.Avalonia.Enums;

var messageBoxStandardWindow = MessageBoxManager
    .GetMessageBoxStandardWindow(new MessageBoxStandardParams
    {
        ContentTitle = "Information",
        ContentMessage = "This is an information message.",
        Icon = Icon.Info,
        ButtonDefinitions = ButtonEnum.Ok
    });
```

Unfortunately, upon execution, it yields the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.IDisposable Avalonia.AvaloniaObjectExtensions.Bind(Avalonia.IAvaloniaObject, Avalonia.AvaloniaProperty, Avalonia.Data.IBinding, System.Object)'.'
```

I'm not sure how to fix it since I'm using the latest versions of all packages.
Rebuilding the solution did not work. I'm using `.NET 7`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the MessageBox.Avalonia version 2.2.0 and install MessageBox.Avalonia version 2.0.0. It should work.